# Tem como transferir os dados do MySQL direto pra uma tabela no Excel?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

Tem alguma forma de transferir toda informação do banco de dados para uma tabela no Excel? Pode ser com qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Verifica a ver se te ajuda https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_guide_to_importing

Comment: Você precisa exatamente de que? Uma função em um possível sistema que faça a importação para excel?

Comment: Bom dia amigo, o proprio excel tem a opção de exportar para CSV. Após abrir voce pode salvar com xls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode exportar para CSV (dados separados com virgula), que o Excel abre normalmente. Se estiver usando PHPMyAdmin, ele tem uma opção exclusiva para esta exportação.

Se estiver usando a ferramenta MySQL Workbench, [neste link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html) ensina passo-a-passo como exportar por ele.

Ou por linha de comando ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM bancodedados.tabela
INTO OUTFILE 'arquivo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Fácil amigo, [Instale essa versão ou superior do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) certifique-se de instalar **MySQL For Excel** e prontinho, dentro do Excel 2007 ou superior no fim da aba DADOS você encontrara um novo botão **MySQL For Excel** basta configurar a conexão e desfrutar dos benefícios!